# How to make stuff concave - large radius - with handtools?

Tags: hand-tools

I’m trying to bestow a 5-foot long hollow to a board, to use as support for the base of a midcentury modern tv cabinet. E.g.: the long horizontal member of the leg base in the image below:

[image: midcentury modern tv console]

I’m limited to handtools. Let us suppose I can draw my preferred curve by bending a lath or with a shipcurve. How do I impart the bow?

(it’s about 4-5 feet long)

##### Credits:

The image is a screengrab from a youtube video: https://youtu.be/AVb8ZBAOD0I

Comment: Have you looked at compass planes?

Comment: Hey, long time! Sorry for how this seems as a welcome back but to say there are an abundance of resources out there on how this might be accomplished using a pure hand tools or blended approach would be quite the understatement! In fact just that subject — curves using hand tools — I can't imagine doesn't cover the topic adequately enough to get someone started and a good way along the, er, learning curve.

Comment: fair. I don’t know how if there’s a way to phrase this question in a more specific or reusable way. I’m presented with a lot of options, not sure how to pick. Compass planes, stop cuts and chisel, spokeshaves, rasps, etc. Coping saw won’t work. Maybe bow saw? Presumably those types of light curves are typically done with a bandsaw.

Comment: Funny enough, i’ve accidentally imparted many bows to boards I was trying to true with flat handplanes. But this is (I think) beyond what i can accomplish with a flat plane sole… unless it was a tiny short one.

Comment: *"Compass planes, stop cuts and chisel, spokeshaves, rasps, etc."* Yes, and that is your answer. It's precisely why I didn't add a formal Answer, because the options are already out there easy to find. Then the choice is ENTIRELY up to the user which way to go, based on what tools are available, budget and even simple preference. "*But this is (I think) beyond what i can accomplish with a flat plane sole… unless it was a tiny short one."* Yup, and one way to think of spokeshaves is that they are tiny short planes :-) this is how even flat-soled spokeshaves can be used for long, gentle curves.

Comment: For clarification, when you say ‘hand tools’, are you talking exclusively about unpowered tools, or would a battery jigsaw be a ‘hand tool’?

Comment: unpowered. but i do have a power router accessible. I’ll try something out, and edit if it doesn’t work out